# how to make connection between 2 dataframe based on id when the condition is met?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to extract sentences from a dataframe based on keywords from another dataframe, which i working perfectly, but I have another dataframe for same sentences in another language but in same sequence and same ID so I want to extract the same sentence form the other dataframe as well based on matched ID of the first one is that doable in any kind ? the code I'm trying is this one

```
wdata = pd.read_csv(firstfile, nrows=0).columns[0]
skip = int(wdata.count(' ') == 0)
wdata = pd.read_csv(firstfile, names=['sentences'], skiprows=skip)

data = wdata['sentences'].str.replace('[^\w\s]', ' ')

tdata = pd.read_csv(secondfile, nrows=0).columns[0]
skip = int(tdata.count(' ') == 0)
tdata = pd.read_csv(secondfile, names=['sentences'], skiprows=skip)

sata = tdata['sentences'].str.replace('[^\w\s]', ' ')


keywords=pd.read_csv(dic)

keywords=keywords.loc[keywords['freq'].between(200, 2499, inclusive=False), 'word']


newdata = data[data.str.split(expand=True).isin(keywords.tolist()).any(axis=1)]


update = data[~data.str.split(expand=True).isin(keywords.tolist()).any(axis=1)]


newdata.to_csv("new_data.csv", index=False, header=False)

update.to_csv("update.csv", index=False, header=False)

----------------------
#first dataframe example 
----------------------
#how are you 
#I want to die
#I was home
#I went to sleep at work
#he have a bad reputation
#it was me who went to him 
#have  good sleep home

----------------------
#second  dataframe example 
----------------------
#halaw kuy bashii
#damawe bmrm 
#la malawa bum
#la esh nustm 
#aw kabraya bash nya 
#awa mn bum chum bo lay
#xaweki xosh basar bba la malawa 


----------------------
#the keyward example example 
----------------------
#word   freq
#and    500
#you    450
#me 300
#have   250
#your   240
#sleep  200
#work   150
#home   100
#die    50
```

now this code works fine to give me the wanted sentences from first dataframe but how can I assign it in a way that will grab the sentence from the second dataframe based on matched ID like if the condition is true and it takes the first sentence from dataframe 1 to a new csv file then take sentnece one in dataframe too into a separate  csv as well and so on

this is the code out put im getting

[image]

and I want to get the same IDs based on first dataframe condition met and dump it into new csv for second dataframe as well so this output

[image]

Comment: I think some sample data (in text) with expected output should be nice here.

Comment: @jezrael I added all three dataframe examples as comment inside the code

Comment: Or expected output  from sample data missing?

Comment: I the code is returing sentence 1,5  ,6, 7 from first data set when condition is met I want it to return same ID from second dataframe as well without checking the condition of second dataframe and just dump it to new csv as well

Comment: @jezrael I added output example as well if you can help here will be great bro

Comment: There is same number of rows between both?

Comment: exactly same number both dataframs has 7 sentences in this example which are match

Comment: that is the relation I was thinking but didnt know how to do it when it take ID one from dataframe 1 to newcsv1 take ID 1 of dataframe 2 to newcsv2 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If same number of rows and same index of both DataFrames you can pass mask from first `DataFrame` to second like:

```
print (data.index.equals(df2.index))
True

newdata2 = df2[data.str.split(expand=True).isin(keywords.tolist()).any(axis=1)]
print (newdata2)
                           sentences
0                   halaw kuy bashii
4               aw kabraya bash nya 
5             awa mn bum chum bo lay
6  xaweki xosh basar bba la malawa 1
```

If want match by index:

```
newdata = data[data.str.split(expand=True).isin(keywords.tolist()).any(axis=1)]
print (newdata)
0                  how are you 
4      he have a bad reputation
5    it was me who went to him 
6         have  good sleep home
Name: sentences, dtype: object

newdata2 = df2[df2.index.isin(newdata.index)]
print (newdata2)
                           sentences
0                   halaw kuy bashii
4               aw kabraya bash nya 
5             awa mn bum chum bo lay
6  xaweki xosh basar bba la malawa 1
```

Comment: but will this work because dataframe 2 is not using the same keywards at all

Comment: @programmingfreak - is necessary same index in both (it means also same length, same values), then it working nice.

Comment: regardless of what is inside the second dataframe I just want it to pass exact same sequence

Comment: @programmingfreak - Data are not important, only index values

Comment: I want to pass the value based on index like when dataframe1 meet the condition check the index and pass the same index in second dataframe as well

Comment: let me try it hope it will return the matched senenteces in second dataframe as well

Comment: works more than perfect speechless of the continuous  help you give man really thank you